# Running function in python script from linux runs whole script

Tags: python, linux

```
def parseCommand():
    args = None
    if len (sys.argv) < 2:
        print('no command entered')
        return

    command = sys.argv[1]
    print ('command executed: %s' %command)
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        args = sys.argv[2]
    if len(sys.argv) > 3:
        args = sys.argv[2:]

    commandList = {
                'fA'              : fA(),
                'fB'              : fB(),
                }

    if args == None:
        return commandList[command]
    else:
        return commandList[command](args)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    parseCommand()
```

I am running this script from linux. However when I run python scriptname.py fA or python scriptname.py fB, the script seems to run just from top to bottom, executing both functions
When I change it to

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    fA()
```

or

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    fB()
```

and run python scriptname.py frtom linux it only executes the function I am calling.

Could anyone tell me what s wrong with my approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're creating `commandList` wrong; the parentheses after `fA` and `fB` are calling the functions:

```
commandList = {
            'fA'              : fA(),
            'fB'              : fB(),
            }                     ~~ <-- remove these parentheses
```

Comment: In addition, you'll need to change the line "return commandList[command]" to "return commandList[command]()"